# C++ and pulseaudio "not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, audio, g++, pulseaudio

I'm trying to use pulseaudio to play the contest of a vorbis-stream but are hitting problems. Basicly I'm told that:

```
‘pa_simple’ was not declared in this scope
‘pa_simple_new’ was not declared in this scope
‘pa_simple_write’ was not declared in this scope
```

Some code are shown below:

```
#include <pulse/pulseaudio.h>
```

---

```
pa_simple *s;
pa_sample_spec ss;

ss.format = PA_SAMPLE_S16NE;
ss.channels = 2;
ss.rate = 44100;

s = pa_simple_new(
    NULL,               // Use the default server.
    "Fooapp",           // Our application's name.
    PA_STREAM_PLAYBACK, // Playback
    NULL,               // Use the default device.
    "Music",            // Description of our stream.
    &ss,                // Our sample format.
    NULL,               // Use default channel map
    NULL,               // Use default buffering attributes.
    NULL,               // Ignore error code.
);
```

---

```
while((samples=vorbis_synthesis_pcmout(&vd,&pcm))>0){
    int j;
    int bout=(samples<convsize?samples:convsize);
    cout << "D" << endl;
    for(i=0;i<vi.channels;i++){
        ogg_int16_t *ptr=convbuffer+i;
        float  *mono=pcm[i];
        for(j=0;j<bout;j++){
            int val=floor(mono[j]*32767.f+.5f);
            *ptr=val;
            ptr+=vi.channels;
        }
    }
    cout << "E" << endl;
    #ifdef PulseAudio
    pa_simple_write(s,convbuffer,2*vi.channels,NULL);
    #else
    fwrite(convbuffer,2*vi.channels,bout,output);
    #endif
    vorbis_synthesis_read(&vd,bout);
    cout << "F" << endl;
}
```

It's probably some simple error, but if anyone could point me into the right direction, that would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those things are all defined in **simple.h**, so add a new `#include` to the top of your file:

```
#include <pulse/simple.h>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much; thought all files where included in pulseaudio.h after having a look in it but I must have missed it. Thanks pal!